# How to print on same line using console.log() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logging

I want to print a list (var lst=[1,2,3,4,5]) using a loop on the same line. Can I do that in JavaScript ?

Comment: `console.log.apply(null, lst);`.

Comment: @ANS: no, that will print each item of the list on a separate line/log entry.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" and  "on the same line"? What is expected result?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(lst))`?

Comment: Construct your message as a string before your log it. Simple as that.

Comment: Curious how present Question is different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672366/how-to-print-a-pyramid-from-an-array-using-settimeout-in-javascript/43672573#43672573 as to "votes"? Proof there is no empirical way to evaluate how a Question is interpreted, nor the premise of "this question should not be answered". Granted, OP has not changed the requirement, yet requirement at present Question is not clear. What are "print", "on the same line" and "using a loop"? Why is a "loop" necessary?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal Can you include the `javascript` that you tried to resolve inquiry at Question? What issue are you having getting expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Well you can achieve this by doing this. Make an empty string variable and then  concatenate each array value to it, then print it out. This will work

```
 var lst = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var output = "";

for(var i =0; i <= lst.length; i++){
   output += lst[i] + " ";
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

In NodeJS and as long as you didn't change your standard output you can use `process.stdout.write("Something here")` as the standard output of your application is terminal (console).

```
process.stdout.write("Hello ")
process.stdout.write("World")
process.stdout.write("!")
```

> Hello world!

Answer (score 0):

Console.log doesn't allow you to print in the same line. However the task that you are trying to do can be done using the below:

```
console.log(lst.join(" "))
```

Output: 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

The exact behavior of `console.log` is not specified by ECMAScript, so it varies from implementation to implementation, but it is intended to be used for logging events. The fact that each event usually becomes a single line in a web browser's console window led it to be the Node.js equivalent of "println", but outside the context of a specific implementation its behavior is not predictable.

You can pass multiple parameters to `log`, in which case most (but not all) implementations will print them all out on the same line separated by whitespace. So if you're using one of those implementations, and you have a list and just want all the elements on one line separated by space, you can use `apply` to call the method as if each element of the list was a separate argument:

```
console.log.apply(console, lst);
```

Caveat: if the first argument is a string that contains what look like `Formatter` format control sequences (`%s`, etc.), it will be parsed as such and the remaining arguments used to fill in those slots.

But the most reliable way to achieve the desired result is to build a single string yourself representing what you want the final line to look like, and then call `console.log` exactly once with that string as the argument.

Comment: The latter also won't print on a single line in Safari. In fact, it's probably sensible to say that (especially in browsers), console.log doesn't really give you much in the way of guarantees of what it will do with arbitrary (and multiple) arguments. If you want something to be on the same 'line', you should give it a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Function#apply` or [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log.apply(null, list); // traditional
console.log(...list);          // ES6
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it easily by using the `join()` function which can be used on any array in JavaScript!

For example:

```
var lst = ["check","word","3","could","hello"]
console.log(lst.join())
```

source-code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdurxsb/